# Is this question asking too much?

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Question:**

> Let $N\triangleleft G$ and $K\triangleleft G$. If $N\cap K=\langle
>  e\rangle$ and $N\vee K=G$, then $G/N\cong K$.

I used the second theorem of isomorphisms and this one (From Hungerford's book):

[image]

Thus:

$K\cong K/\langle e\rangle\cong G/N$ (by second theorem of isomorphisms)

So I only use $N\triangleleft G$, am I wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is "$\;N\vee K\;$" the product of subgroups $\;NK\;$ ?

Comment: Ok, checked it: it's just the subgroup generated by them...which is the product if, for example, at least one of the groups is normal.

Comment: @DonAntonio so, I'm right.

Comment: Yes @user42912 , you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $G=NK$ because $N$ is normal in $G$, so $N\vee K=NK$; by the homomorphism theorem
$$
\frac{G}{N}=\frac{NK}{N}\cong\frac{K}{K\cap N}=\frac{K}{\{e\}}\cong K.
$$
Indeed, the normality of $K$ is not necessary.

Comment: In fact $K$ is said to be complement of $N$ in $G$. Only the normality of $N$ is required.